# Multiple search provider boxes in Firefox

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions

I am using 3-5 search providers usually when browsing. However, default search box only allows to manually change search provider and then perform search. I'm looking for the way to have multiple boxes with different search providers where I can enter my keywords and search. Is there solution for latest firefox?

Comment: Are there keyword based solutions? For instance, if you want to search via Bing type "bing (your search terms)" or Google "google (your search terms)" or Yahoo "yahoo (your search terms)". I believe Firefox natively supports keywords in the awesome bar and this may be a solution that uses less toolbar space.

Comment: not good enough.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you use so many search providers?

Comment: Youtube, The Free Dictionary, Google, Python... it would be easiler to just type keyword in specific box. However, I realize there is no extension for that, sadly...

Comment: I really wish they'd add support for custom searches in the AwesomeBar HD addon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [**DuckDuckGo**](https://duckduckgo.com). It's a search engine which allows you also to use other search engines.

If you put !b (bing), !g (google), !y (yahoo), !yt (youtube),... in your request, it will search on this site instead of DDG. "!python subprocess" will directly search for the library subprocess in the python documentation.
The list of 1588 (so far) different sites supported can be found [here](https://duckduckgo.com/bang.html).

There is of course [a firefox addon](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/duck-duck-go-ssl-search-plugin/) and it's possible to use it as default search engine on many browser (cf bottom of [this page](https://duckduckgo.com/tools.html)).

It's not multiple search boxes but if you want to search on many different websites, do have a look.

Answer (score 1):

Try Quick search bar Firefox add on.  Though it is not the exact solution.  I hope this close.

More details [here](http://www.browsomatic.com/2010/12/switch-search-engines-in-search-bar.html) and go [here](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/quicksearch/) to try it.